# Deferred Event list maintained in DefaultStateMachineExecutor is lost in spring state machine

Tags: deferred, state-machine, executor, spring-statemachine

**Background:**

In our typical working model of state machine , we use state machine to monitor spring-batch processing done by spring cloud stream micro-services . 
More precisely saying we create stream ,say, named ItemStream , having source , process , sink micro services deployed that read , process and write records in bulk ; respectively . 
While doing these activities , we fire REST calls each call consisting of one event in between the operations of streams. These REST calls we consume in State Machine micro-service and fire those events within accordingly , on machine instance . Here at state machine level each time once processing is done , we persist state machine context to the persistent store (database/Redis cache) using JPA/Redis State Machine Persister . 
And when new REST call is received from streams , we restore back the machine context from the persistent store and populate one fresh state machine object with it ; so as to prepare that fresh machine object to have a state of the machine as existed previously . 
**Note:** Here 'populate the fresh state machine object' simply means we create each time new instance using machine factory calls , as we are yet to plug the machine object pool implementation to push and pop used objects of StateMachine as and when needed rather than creating fresh new instance every time .

**Problem :**

However , now problem we are facing is ,  we have configured the deferred event (say for e.g.CompleteChunk_1 ) for particular state(e.g. state PROCESSEDCHUNK ) in uml file.
Now after firing CompleteChunk_1 event when machine is at PROCESSEDCHUNK state , this event does get deferred i.e. parked aside correctly . Now it is expected that machine should fire this parked event on its own whenever that particular future state(i.e. WRITECHUNK ) is reached for which that event was mapped in a transition .
But once machine reaches at that state i.e. at WRITECHUNK state , the machine is not firing that CompleteChunk_1 event on its own which was parked previously in machines deferred list .

**Observations**

**1.**After trouble shooting the issue what I could notice is State machine's member property 'stateMachineExecutor' holds the  DefaultStateMachineExecutor instance who maintains the deferred list in a data structure 'ConcurrentLinkedList' within itself .  This executor is every time instantiated to the new one in an onInit() method of state machine in AbstractStateMachine class . So I believe each time whenever fresh instance is created from factory and machine object is revived with the previous persisted context ,  we are losing the deferred events that were parked in that executor's "deferredList" . Because OOB persistence/restoring does not persist/restore the executor's state thus deferred list present on that executor will be lost . 
So in our case by the time when machine comes to the correct state i.e. WRITECHUNK , the executor has already lost the deferred event that was parked in past event calls . Thus they can not be now fired by machine automatically because parked events now don't exist in executor.

**2.**In simple state machine examples given on spring documentation I tried to configured deferred events and it worked correctly and after valid state was reached parked events did get fired automatically . In these examples , state machine was launched and running constantly since then from first event to the last event. Thus same instance object of machine holding that same DefaultStateMachineExecutor instance till end worked .

3.Maven dependency lib versions are as below :

a.spring-statemachine-core : 2.0.0 
b.spring-statemachine-uml :  2.0.0

**Requesting for a Solution ??**

So is there any design change needed or a way to deal with this situation of DefaultStateMachineExecutor when looking at the fact that we persist the context and restore it on each REST call that is received ?? Or I am miss understanding something regarding above mentioned conclusions which I have arrived at while troubleshooting ??

**Thanking you in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this going to need some changes in a machine itself. It's a little complex issue and generally speaking we need to overhaul other event related things with persistence. These are tracked in [gh-550](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/550)