# Deferred Event in Spring State Machine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have been trying to implement the below State machine using the spring-state machine.
Please find the configurations below.

[image]

I have been using spring-state machine for one of my project.

```
public class StateMachineConfiguration extends AbstractStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {


    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<String, String> config) throws Exception {

        config.withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<String, String> state) throws Exception {
        //Taking all base states
        Set<String> possibleState = new HashSet<>();// add all states

        state.withStates()
                .initial(CREATED)
                .state(CREATED, DELIVER) //Deferred Event definition
                .end(COMPLETED)
                .end(FAILED)
                .states(possibleState);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<String, String> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
                .withExternal()
                .source(CREATED)
                .target(CREATED)
                .event(CREATE)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(CREATED)
                .target(PROCESSING)
                .event(PROCESS)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(PROCESSING)
                .target(COMPLETED)
                .event(DELIVER)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(PROCESSING)
                .target(FAILED)
                .event(FAILED)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(CREATED)
                .target(CANCELLED)
                .event(CANCEL)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(PROCESSING)
                .target(CANCELLED)
                .event(CANCEL);
    }
}
```

There is a chance that `Deliver` event might come before `Process` event and to handle that I have been trying to use spring deferred events.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#sm-deferevents

With the above configuration, the State machine is accepting `Deliver` event even at `Created` state, but not processing that deferred event when state machine has received `Processing` event. I have been using `RedisStateMachinePersistence` to persist state machine.

Comment: Spring boot: `'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.8.RELEASE'`
spring-state-machine version: `group: 'org.springframework.statemachine', name: 'spring-statemachine-core', version: '2.2.0.RELEASE'`

Comment: Seems like this is onging bug into spring state machine library.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954727/deferred-event-list-maintained-in-defaultstatemachineexecutor-is-lost-in-spring